# Google Charts tooltip options

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, google-visualization

I am new to Javascript but my customer wants to have different tooltip background,border and text color. Since I am new I don't know what should I change or put in code. Thank you in advance! (style goes for tooltips generated at hovering, not adding extra ones)

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBackgroundColor);

function drawBackgroundColor(transparent) {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'X');
data.addColumn('number', 'Xaurum Gold Growth');


data.addRows([
[new Date(2015 , 03 , 15),0.000125],
[new Date(2015 , 04 , 09),0.000125202590875],
[new Date(2015, 04, 12), 0.000126019393875],

]);
var options = {
hAxis: {
  title: 'Time',
  textStyle:{color: '#FFF'},
  titleTextStyle: {
color: '#fff'
}
},
vAxis: {
  title: 'Value',
  textStyle:{color: '#FFF'},
  titleTextStyle: {
color: '#fff'
}
},
legend: {
textStyle: {color: '#fff'}
},
NumberFormat: {
fractionDigits:15,
},
annotations: {
boxStyle: {
stroke: '#765e34',
strokeWidth: 10,
}
},
backgroundColor: "transparent",
colors: ['#876c3c'],


};

 var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('charta_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want to style the default tooltip, without providing custom tooltip,

add the following configuration option

`tooltip: {isHtml: true}`

then you will be able to use the following css selector

`.google-visualization-tooltip`

if you need to style something already defined by google,
you may need to increase the specificity by using `!important`,
depending on how/where your css is defined

you may also need to add additional selectors, depending on the element to be styled, such as...

`.google-visualization-tooltip span`

you can use the "Elements" tab in the Developers Tools of most browsers,
to investigate the current html tags and styles used in the tooltip.
add `tooltip: {trigger: 'selection'}` to lock the tooltip in place while investigating

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBackgroundColor);

function drawBackgroundColor(transparent) {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('date', 'X');
data.addColumn('number', 'Xaurum Gold Growth');


data.addRows([
[new Date(2015 , 03 , 15),0.000125],
[new Date(2015 , 04 , 09),0.000125202590875],
[new Date(2015, 04, 12), 0.000126019393875],

]);
var options = {
hAxis: {
  title: 'Time',
  textStyle:{color: '#FFF'},
  titleTextStyle: {
color: '#fff'
}
},
vAxis: {
  title: 'Value',
  textStyle:{color: '#FFF'},
  titleTextStyle: {
color: '#fff'
}
},
legend: {
textStyle: {color: '#fff'}
},
NumberFormat: {
fractionDigits:15,
},
annotations: {
boxStyle: {
stroke: '#765e34',
strokeWidth: 10,
}
},
backgroundColor: "transparent",
colors: ['#876c3c'],
// use html tooltips
tooltip: {isHtml: true}

};

 var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```css
.google-visualization-tooltip {
  background-color: yellow !important;
  border: 2px solid cyan !important;
}

.google-visualization-tooltip span {
  color: magenta !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you WhiteHat, you helped me anytime and all your solutions worked more than lerfect! Can't thank you more! Gotta start learning JS

Answer (score 0):

```
// Add a new column for storing tooltip properties to the end
data.addColumn({'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': {'html': true}});
..
..   
// Now the rows you add will have this new property set. last column
// You will need to do this for remaining rows as required
[new Date(2015 , 03 , 15),0.000125,createCustomHTMLContent('blue',0.000125)],


//This is the function that will return html formatted tooltip.
//only sample. you will need to make changes according to your needs
function createCustomHTMLContent(color, number) {
  return '<div style="padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;background-color:"+ color + ";"><span>' +  number + "</span></div>"
}
```

This may be of help [Annotate and Tooltip](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content#annotating-data)